# How to add stdout and stderr to logger file in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to log the stdout & stderr to log files, and this is what I tried.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # use the native logger of flask
app.logger.disabled = False
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    SYSTEM_LOG_FILENAME,
    'a',
    maxBytes=1024 * 1024 * 100,
    backupCount=20
    )

formatter = logging.Formatter(\
    "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s: \t%(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)

@app.route('/')
def hello():

    return 'Hello World'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then I would like to log the console output in files.
such as

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2013 14:55:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2013 14:55:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

what can I do?

Comment: What does your code do?

Comment: Actually its doing nothing here, but I was trying to log the stdout and stderr to files. And also to log the debug and error info to files

Comment: Change `logging.INFO` to `logging.DEBUG`. That should get you the debug messages as well.

Comment: are you trying to log things you `print`?

Comment: @Blender But how can I get the stdout and stderr info

Comment: @ThomasFenzl Not exactly, since flask will output some stdout or error info in console, I am trying to redirect these things to log file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The logging messages you mention don't come from flask's logger, the [come from](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/60670cb98db1934b7aa7df454cbe4508c467f403/werkzeug/serving.py#L680) `werkzeug`'s [logger](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/60670cb98db1934b7aa7df454cbe4508c467f403/werkzeug/_internal.py#L107), that means you also need to add your handler to that logger instance to make it work, e.g:

```
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(handler)
```

If you look at how werkzeug initializes its logger, you'll see that it adds a default handler only if logging wasn't already set up. That means if you set it up before wekzeug does, it won't use the default `StreamHandler` but the handler you supply.

Comment: Please specify for more detail info, you mean I should also add the 'handler' to werkzeug's logger or should I need to create a new logger

Comment: @mata:  This did it for me; never, ever, *ever* would have figured it out on my own; thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for a solution to this for 2 days.