# Redirect stderr with Flask and uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, stderr

I have a simple Flask app with an error:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    i = 1/0
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

I also have a simple uWSGI server (ini file):

```
[uwsgi]
module = myapp:app
...
```

I want all the Flask errors to be redirected to a separate file `error.log`. So my `error.log` after visiting the route should be:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/ctsahn/test.py", line 7, in hello_world
    i = 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I've tried several things to redirect the Flask errors, including adding
`sys.stderr = open('error.log','wt')` to my Flask app, as well as trying this (and similar methods): [How to add stdout and stderr to logger file in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741834/how-to-add-stdout-and-stderr-to-logger-file-in-flask)

However, the errors are not redirected and only show up on stderr. How can I redirect properly?

Comment: Use the ```--logto``` option of uWSGI.

Comment: @relent95 I tried that, but it seems to just output the entire log (instead of just the stderr) to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flask you can register an error handler to log any error you want. first you need to create / initialize an error logger for example:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

error_handler = RotatingFileHandler('error.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Then you register and app error handler using app.register_error_handler or simple use the error handler decorator for example

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_error(e):

    # assuming that your logger is ready as above you can log the error here
    logger.error(xxxxxx) # whatever you want to log from e

    # for further handling of the error
    if isinstance(e, ZeroDivisionError):
        app.logger.error('ZeroDivisionError: %s', (str(e)))
        return render_template('zero_division_error.html'), 500
    elif isinstance(e, KeyError):
        app.logger.error('KeyError: %s', (str(e)))
        return render_template('key_error.html'), 500
    else:
        app.logger.error('Unhandled Exception: %s', (str(e)))
        return render_template('error.html'), 500
```

Comment: I've been able to log the errors with this; however, it still writes to stderr and not the specified file (error.log).

Comment: Did you set up the logger using this: error_handler = RotatingFileHandler('error.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

Comment: Yes I did. I have a feeling this is a problem with how the Flask logger and uWSGI interact?

Comment: It is working on my end though. Try to log anything and see if the logger is working. Just write logger.error("Test") and check if it goes to the file.